# Apache FOP process several files over command line

Tags: apache-fop

Is it possible to process several files in a row with apache fop when used over the command line?

Comment: you mean multi-threaded ?

Comment: well, i dont now :) right now i just have to transform each file separately. I know how to transform several files when using FOP with Eclipse, in a java application. But right now, I'm just executing the fop command in the windows command-line and that onyl serves for one file at a time, as far as I'm aware.